# Pixel Perfect верстка

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как верстать пиксель в пиксель? В фотошопе беру все отступы, а в итоге когда налаживаю этот же макет в pixelperfect, то всё криво.

Comment: У вас скорее всего проблемы с `line-height` - следите за высотой строки. Ну и да, будьте внимательны :)

Answer (score 2):

У тебя скорее всего отступы от браузера вставлябться, надо использовать чтото типа такого:

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/)

Answer (score 1):

Советы:

1. установить расширение для Chrome [PerfectPixel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=ru);
2. быть внимательным.